# ISAPI Rewrite RewriteRule for domain root username URLs

Tags: asp-classic, url-rewriting, seo, isapi-rewrite

I am trying to create a root username using ISAPI Rewrite.

E.g. `www.mysite.com/myusername`

I want this to redirect to...

```
/user.asp=myusername
```

Then if the username is not found to load content based on the /folder/

Maybe it would be good to check if a file with folder.asp extension exists and if not redirect to user.asp?username=folder

I know the easy option is to just write the .htaccess to reference:

www.domain.com/user/username

But I really want the root URL?

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know the easy option is to just write the **.htaccess** to reference:

I guess your Isapi Rewrite module is [Helicon's 3.0](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/).
Checking file/folder existence using Rewrite Module is more efficient than using scripting language.
Write a rule that compatible with your username format (valid characters etc, see the comments).
Check the matched part. Make the redirect if it's not an exists file / folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
# if the file does not exist
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f
# if the folder does not exist
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d
# from start to end, "^(\w+)[/]+$" only matches with one or more alphanumeric characters and "_".
# alternatively can end with one or more slashes.
# change [R = 302, L] to [L] if you want make a rewrite instead of redirect.
RewriteRule ^(\w+)[/]*$ /user.asp?username=$1 [R = 302, L]
```

Comment: That is really great! but is there a way to not redirect to /user.asp?username=$1 URL but to just display the content?

Comment: Oh actually I just realised the comments!